DeprecationWarning: The `ipykernel.comm.Comm` class has been deprecated. Please use the `comm` module instead
I'm trying to build recommendation engine using Azure Databricks notebook by using the algorithm from mlxtend library. I'm able to train the model successfully. However, there is a warning during training process as shown in the screenshot below:

I have tried to upgrade ipykernel ipywidgets through %pip install --upgrade ipykernel ipywidgets but the warning still there. May I know how should I do in order to avoid this warning? Thank you.

I'd say you need to step in there with a debugger and find out what called the code that threw the warning. ideally you'd want a traceback but idk how to get that for a warning.

I added some relevant tags. there might also be some tqdm involved (using the ipywidgets progress bar there). in general, update all the python packages. maybe that'll do it.

I have tried the below approach to avoid the below warning:

frequent_itemsets = apriori(df.drop(columns=['user_id']), min_support=0.6, use_colnames=True)
print("Frequent Itemsets:")
print(frequent_itemsets)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="confidence", min_threshold=0.7)
print("\nAssociation Rules:")
print(rules[['antecedents', 'consequents', 'support', 'confidence']]
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning, message="DataFrames with non-bool types result in worse computational performance")


By adding warnings.filterwarnings(“ignore”),you can suppress the warnings that are being displayed during the training process.
Results:
Frequent Itemsets:
   support  itemsets
0      0.6  (item_A)
1      0.6  (item_B)
2      0.6  (item_C)
3      0.6  (item_D)

Association Rules:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [antecedents, consequents, support, confidence]
Index: []


